# css hover info display

Tags: css, popup, hover

ok it's supposed to be really simple but for some reason it isn't working. when i hover over an image a box with information is supposed to pop up like when you hover over a question mark and the question is answered.

```css
.infodot {
  position: relative;
}
.redinfo {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: 280px;
  display:none;
}
.infodot:hover .redinfo {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.brokenarrowwear.com/embroidery/img/infodot.png" class="infodot" />
<p class="redinfo"><strong>PLEASE NOTE</strong> - Info dot information</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 'next sibling', `actually: adjacent sibling selector`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

```
.infodot:hover + .redinfo {
  display: block;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/d1taznfb/

Another option is to change your markup, so you can use different selector(s).